GitLab comments "on an outdated change" unreadable and unresolvable
In a GitLab merge request I'm reviewing, many of my comments have changed to this form:
\<username\> \<@usertag\> started a thread on an outdated change in commit xxxxxxxx
1 week ago
Last updated 18 hours ago by \<creator\>

There's only one control associated with such a comment: a link that hides it (and also hides the entire range of lines it applies to), or when it is hidden, a link that unhides it.
There are no controls for editing the comment or marking it resolved. I can't even see what I wrote in order to decide whether the creator's change does resolve it.
Oh, and I can't make any new comments, either. The "C" icon that should appear when I float the mouse pointer over the left margin of a line is no longer there.
What am I supposed to do with this? It seems to make my task as a reviewer impossible.
